# How to run laravel artisan command on server?

Tags: laravel

How to run laravel artisan command on server? I have to run this this command:

```sh
composer require realrashid/sweet-alert
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have access for ssh, login through it.

Check if you have composer by typing `composer` in terminal else install it.

to Install `composer` use `composer install` command in terminal.

go to the root folder in which laravel is installed using cd command.

In the root folder, run the command `php artisan` in terminal.

It should work fine now.

**What if you have Shared hosting?**

Just look for `terminal` in cpanel. See image for ref..

[image]

Open it and try for the steps given above.

Thank you!

Comment: Terminal option is not avaialble into my cpanel

Comment: then check for ssh access if you have?

Comment: Yes i have ssh access

Comment: then login through ssh and follow the given steps

Comment: @Rohit Do you know how to run php artisan commands on an application using AWS Systems Manager - Run Commands?